# Getting a specific line from a file in python without reading the entire file?

Tags: python-3.x

A program I'm working on takes a text file as an input and outputs it as an animation. I want it to read the file line-by-line instead of processing the entire file at once as it might slow down the player with larger files. Is it possible to read just one line of a file without loading the entire file?

Answer (score 0):

File has to loaded all at once using `open()` but you can control how content of file is read for example

```
with open(filename.txt,r) as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
for line in lines:
    print(line)
```

Comment: No, it does not have to loaded *all at once*. You can read it character by character or line by line. You can even seek to some location and read from there.

Comment: How do I do that?